# Detect prerender view in PHP?

Tags: php, http-headers

How can I detect a prerender page view in PHP?

When I use prerender it messes up my page view counter.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about **web development** which is off-topic at Pro Webmasters. Web development questions may be asked at [so] but be sure to read their [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/help) before posting to ensure your question meets their guidelines.